# spark join takes too much time before failure only when one of the data frames in the join gets mutated

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I have two data frames, one is loaded from csv **dfCsv** and the other is loaded from Aurora DB **dfRds**.
I do a full outer join between the two data frames, and print the join execution plan and every thing is OK, it takes like 5 minutes(the join) because my data volume is something around 5 gb.
from the execution plan, I find that dfRds is already existing in the time of join

My problem happens when I apply a very simple mutation to **dfRds** like

```
dfRds = dfRds.na.fill(" ")
```

I start to get errors in the executors, and it seems that the driver can't communicate with them anymore, and after 4 retrials the glue job is terminated with an exception.

by checking the execution plan after applying the mutation, I found that dfRds is getting scanned instead of already existing (the case without mutating **dfRds**)

my code is as simple as this

```
dfCsv = // load from csv
dfRds = // load from rds
dfJoin = dfCsv.join(dfRds, dfRds("pk") = dfCsv("")  ,"fullouter").filter("some conditions")
```

any explanation why I get this problem? and how can work around it?

error :

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 50.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 0.3 in stage 50.0 (TID 258) ( executor 11): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 11 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason:
> Executor heartbeat timed out after 160497 ms

Comment: Can you add the error stack trace to your question?

Comment: Also, are you sure your join actually executes? `join` and `filter` are both Spark transformations, meaning that they are lazy operations that only happen when an action has been called. More on this [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations)

Comment: yes, I am sure in case of no muatations...I have updated the post with the error

Comment: May be it works because I collect the data frame as list, so this would be the action triggering the execution @Koedlt

Comment: Ahh yes `collect` is indeed the action that triggers everything! So what you've shared here is just the error on the driver side (saying that it can't find the executor, because it died). Could you share with us the error on the executor side, the cluster size and your full code? At this point, it's hard to answer your question (we don't have the full code, we don't know the size of you cluster, size of your data, and we don't know what the actual error is)